# xargs to move files to a user specified location

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to make a program which moves the files which have been modified within the last 30 minutes to a location specified by the user. The line below doesn't work

`cat ~/temporary_file.txt | xargs -i mv {} $response`

`temporary_file.txt` stores the files which are to be moved and `response` is the location specified by the user of where to move the files. Whenever I try run the program, regardless of what `response` is even for `~/` it will say the 'cannot move [filename] to '~/': No such file in directory'. Is there anything I can do to make the program work?

UPDATE:

Solved the issue by using an `if` statement to detect whether the start of `response` started with `~/` then used the following line to manually expand `~`

`response="$HOME"/"${response:2}"`

Comment: Tilde expansion happens before variable expansion, so for `$response` being exactly `~/` [you get exactly `~/`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/709885/108618), even if `$response` is unquoted ([it should be double-quoted](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767/108618)). This is not an answer because it's about the tilde only, it does not address the general case ("regardless of what `response` is").

Comment: How exactly do you assign a value to the variable named `response`?

Comment: Can you give us an idea what is in `~/temporary_file.txt`? try a `head -3` or so, And,  what does `echo "$response"`  give?

Comment: `~/temporary_file.txt` contains a bunch of files in the current directory starting with ```./``` and seperated by new lines

Answer (score 0):

I assume `$response` contains a path to an existing directory. Then this should help:

```
xargs -I {} echo mv {} "$response" < ~/temporary_file.txt
```

or

```
xargs echo mv -t "$response" < ~/temporary_file.txt
```

If output looks okay, remove `echo`.

See: `man xargs`